# Is every jordan homomorphism a ring homomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, multiplicative-function, ring-homomorphism

Let $A$ and $B$ be Banach algebras. A linear map $\phi: A\longrightarrow B$ is called a Jordan Homomorphism if $\phi(a^2)=\phi(a)^2$ for every $a\in A$. And $\phi$ is a ring Homomorphism if $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$ for every $a,b\in A$.

Is every Jordan Homomorphism a ring Homomorphism? I know that every Jordan Homomorphism is a ring Homomorphism if $B$ is a commutative semisimple Banach algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appear that commutativity of both $A$ and $B$ is sufficient, as can be seen from the following computation. Let $a,b\in A$ be arbitrary, then one sees
\begin{align}
\phi(a)^{2} + \phi(b)^{2} + \phi(a)\phi(b) + \phi(b) \phi(a) &= (\phi(a) + \phi(b))^{2} \\
&= \phi((a+b)^{2}) \\
&= \phi(a)^{2} + \phi(b)^{2} + \phi(ab) + \phi(ba).
\end{align}
In general, we see that the equation
\begin{equation}
\phi(a)\phi(b) + \phi(b) \phi(a) = \phi(ab) + \phi(ba),
\end{equation}
holds.

Let us thus try to find a counter-example where both $A$ and $B$ are non-commutative. A simple choice would be $A = B = \text{Mat}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$. Now define the map $\phi$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\phi:\text{Mat}_{2}(\mathbb{R}) &\rightarrow \text{Mat}_{2}(\mathbb{R}),\\
a & \mapsto a^{T},
\end{align}
where $a^{T}$ is the transpose of the matrix $a$. A simple verification shows that this map is a Jordan homomorphism, but not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very simple example. But you say Note that if A is commutative, then, the image of $\phi$ is commutative as well. How is that true?

Comment: My bad, this is of course true when $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism, but I don't see how it follows if $\phi$ is just a Jordan homomorphism. I have edited my answer.